# run monkey_recorder.py error: mismatched input 'monkey_recorder' expecting NEWLINE

Tags: monkeyrunner, recorder, monkey

When I tried to use monkeyrunner command to run recorder, I got the error: mismatched input 'monkey_recorder' expecting NEWLINE.
Here is screenshot of my command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpOVR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which will give you some advantages over `monkeyrunner` and `monkey_recorder`. For example, instead of recording the screen coordinates for a touch, `culebra` records the selector of the View touched so the script or test will be screen coordinates agnostic.

See [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) page for details.